# SSL Certificate error for ruby gems v 2.5.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ssl-certificate

```
heroku run rake db:seed
```

was failing to execute our scrape.

Running

```
rake db:seed
```

in development give the following error message:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

I followed the steps here https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88, but still not working.

I am using ruby 2.2.1, and ruby gems version 2.5.0.

Please help! :)

Solution:
Updated to El Capitan, and all ruby gems. Works now.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of possibilities for RoR to get into this problem.  Please checkout this resource which introduced several solutions. Hope you can find your problem in one of this.

[OpenSSL Errors and Rails – Certificate Verify Failed](http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html)

NOTE: make sure you have added `.pem` file as ssl certificate to your environment

Comment: thanks for the response. I updated to Ruby 2.2.3 and now getting a more specific error message, telling me it was a problem with my Google API access. And now my google console seems to be unavailable, so must be a problem with the google service atm.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku ssl cert is signed with digicert.com, So you should have their root certificate on your machine. Maybe it is in package ca-certificates ( Please check )

One way to get it work is to add digicert root certificate into openssl cert path so here:
Assume that cert.pem is digicert.com root CA

```
cert_file="$( openssl version -d | awk -F'"' '{print $2}' )/cert.pem"
cat cert.pem > $sert_file
```

OR set this constants in rake file 
    OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE